# ServletContextListener Issue | HTTP Status 404 -

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, http-status-code-404, servletcontextlistener

It has been observed that whenever I add a `Listener` class to my `web.xml`, the whole Web application stops functioning. Please find the code below :

web.xml

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>Reminder</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Reminder.java

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {
        response.getWriter().print("Initasdadsa");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reminder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
        try {
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

When I deploy the .war file of the above application it says :

```
HTTP Status 404 - type Status report
message description The requested resource is not available.Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
```

The Tomcat log file is as follows :

```
May 9, 2013 3:57:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/CloudStorage]
May 9, 2013 3:57:10 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed         
to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the   
JDBC    Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 9, 2013 3:57:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive CloudStorage.war
May 9, 2013 3:57:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 9, 2013 3:57:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/CloudStorage] startup failed due to previous errors
May 9, 2013 3:57:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed       
to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the 
JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

When I omit the `Listener` part, the application is working fine. :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the whole Reminder.class , as the source code you posted doesnt compile right now

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the full qualified name of the Reminder class like "com.example.Reminder" in your web.xml unless your class is in the default package.

If it's in the default package then there may be another problem.

Comment: It's in the default package.

Comment: Where the "response" variable in the contextInitialized method is initialized? Are you sure it's not null?

Comment: +1 ; @user1640534: just don't use the default package, ts use is discouraged and leads to some side effects in Tomcat.

Comment: Tried changing to a package! But, still the issue persists !